# Find context between multiple similar lazy ending groups

Tags: regex

What is the most efficient expression to solve finding context between multiple similar lazy quantifiers on a multi line.

I’m using HTML as the test subject so it is easier to comprehend rather the true format (symbols and character bytes), otherwise would be using a Xpath/DOM!

Sample data:

```
<div>
     Testing 1234 
     <div>Testing1234</div> and testing 
     <div>Testing1234</div> testing 1234
</div>
```

Desired result:

```
Testing 1234 
         <div>Testing1234</div> and testing 
         <div>Testing1234</div> testing 1234
```

PCRE Expressions

```
Base: /(<div>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/
Non capturing group: /(<div>)((?:<div>.*?<\/div>).*?)(<\/div>)/
```

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML

Comment: Are you stuck with regex or is it possible for you to use xpath?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @anubhava I’m not parsing parsing HTML, but the test subject for ease of reading the problem is designed in HTML, figured that was easier to comprehend.

Comment: @Monofuse added more detail above. This is not a xpath solution.

Comment: You need a [recursive regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) to match nested: [`(?s)<div>((?:(?:(?!<\/?div).)+|(?R))*+)<\/div>`](https://regex101.com/r/IYnp1p/1) (this sample-regex will only work if data is like your sample, result will be [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) of *first group*)

Comment: Just to mention, will be more efficient if you use [negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `<` instead of the `(?:(?!<\/?div).)+` part: [`<div>((?:[^<]+|<(?!\/?div\b)|(?R))*+)<\/div>`](https://regex101.com/r/RCkzW6/2) (we can also drop the dotall flag `(?s)` here as there is no dot used).

Comment: @bobblebubble awesome - my answer has been found, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would require [recursive](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) regex to match the nested.  (Answer provided by @bobble bubble)

*The following will match the first group:*

```
(?s)<div>((?:(?:(?!<\/?div).)+|(?R))*+)<\/div>
```

*More efficient by using "[negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) **<**":*

```
(?:(?!<\/?div).)+ part: <div>((?:[^<]+|<(?!\/?div\b)|(?R))*+)<\/div>
```